# Perform calculation in hex with Qalculate

Tags: calculator

I'm trying to do hex calculations, `C - A`, and I already changed number base to hex, but Qalculate still doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is interpreting `C` and `A` as units. ([Coulombs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb) and [Amperes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampere).)

The button where you selected “Hexadecimal” only applies when displaying the result. It doesn't affect the way the expression that you enter is parsed.

Try `0xC - 0xA`.